# Nginx serve cached version on first visit

Tags: wordpress, nginx, caching

We have a multi-currency setup on a WordPress site I'm working on (Kinsta shared hosting). When we change the currency, a cookie is set with the selected currency's ISO. Also when the site loads, a cookie is set with the preselected currency (USD by default).

We had issues with currency switching not working because we'd always get the cached default site. So they added a custom rule to the nginx config something like

```
if ($http_cookie ~* "current_currency") {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}
```

What happens now is that the user comes to the site, gets the uncached version, switches the currency (another uncached version) then when you switch it back to the currency you've visited you get a cache HIT.

What I'm curious about, if it's possible at all, is to always get the cached version, no matter if you came for the first time to the site or not, as long as the cache exists (currently cache expiration is set to 4 hours).

Since the default currency of the site is always USD can we add something like

```
if ($http_cookie ~* "current_curency" && $http_cookie.value !== 'USD') {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}
```

(this is probably pseudocode)

so that we always get a cache HIT, even on the first-page visit (if the cache is primed ofc)?

I've seen a similar issue with WPML [here](https://wpml.org/errata/caching-plugins-may-cause-issues-with-wcml-multi-currency-settings/), and I do have a similar `setcookie` functionality, but I'm not sure about the last part

> Strip all $http_cookies that are still cached on cache HITS, this will avoid the cookie from being set up on pages that hit the Kinsta cache to avoid bypassing Kinsta cache where we don’t need to bypass Kinsta cache.

How to strip the cookies that are cached on cache HITS?